# Is there PHP shorthand for : if (a) {var = a}

Tags: php

In PHP is there a shorter or better way of writing :

`If ($a) {$var = $a}`

My main aim is to :

- only instantiate the variable ($var) if $a exists. (in the real world $a is a function returning a value if found in a string search).
- not repeat the mention of $a.

Comment: Variables should exist unconditionally, simply with default values. If you take that to heart, then something like `$var = $a ?: $var` would do.

Comment: Do you mean something like the `??` null coalescing operator?

Comment: You are looking for something like `$var ??= $a;`

Comment: back to the problem at hand.... I appreciate the replies so far so thank you. However it is important to me that the variable is only declared if $a exists.  Let's say $var is an array and I need to only assign a key to it ($var["a"]) if $a exists. If I were to repeat the described methods I could end up with an array with plenty of defined keys but with null values. In an ideal world I need to keep that array clean and only define keys that are necessary.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention arrays, so it's not surprising nobody is offering solutions for them.

Comment: @IMSoP The question does not need to mention arrays.  The main points are addressed. I only want to declare the variable if $a exists.  The extra information regarding arrays was only mentioned to show why I don't want to declare $var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such shorthand exists. However you can accomplish the same thing like this:

```
$var = $a;
if (!$var) {
    unset($var);
}
```

If $var is falsey (0, "0", "", null, empty, or false) it will be unset as if it had not been instantiated in the first place.

Edit:

unset also works on array indexes such as the following:

```
unset($var['a']);
```

The above wouldn't just set the value to null. It would set it to null and remove it from the array.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
$temp = $a;
if ($temp) {
    $array['a'] = $temp;
}
else {
    unset($temp);
}
```

You can also accomplish what you desire with a function:

```
function add_value_if_exists(&$array, $key, $value) {
    if ($value) {
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }
}

add_value_if_exists($array, 'a', $a);
```

In the above $array will only be modified if $a is truthy.

Comment: Thanks all for your input. I was hovering around the idea of just writing a method or function for this purpose and it seems that this will be the best solution. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two operators that do something similar to what you're looking for:

- The "shorthand ternary" or "Elvis" operator, `?:`
- The "null coalesce" operator, `??`

Both are a kind of "inline if": `$var = $a ?: $b` means something like "set $var to $a if it's truthy, $b otherwise"; `$var = $a ?? $b` is similar, but tests for "exists and not null" rather than "truthy".

There's also a combined assignment operator `??=` which leaves the variable untouched if the *left-hand side* is not unset or null, so acts as a way to provide defaults. That's sort of the opposite of what you wanted, but in many scenarios you can write code like this:

```
$blah = somefunc();
$blah ??= $default;
```

PHP does not have the ability to explicitly declare variables (there is, for instance, no `var` keyword or type declaration like `int $counter;`) so there can be no syntax for the exact requirement you've written. In languages that do have explicit variable declarations, it wouldn't make sense for them to be conditional, since they're usually intended to be checked statically (i.e. "at compile time").

Comment: As stipulated in the original question and now augmented to reflect this example; I do not wish to declare "blah" unless "somefunc()" returns true.